# Matplotlib bar chart on datetime index values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having trouble getting the following code to display a bar chart properly. The plot has very thin lines which are not visible until you zoom in, but even then it's not clear. I've tried to control with the width option to `plt.bar()` but it's not doing anything (e.g. tried 0.1, 1, 365).

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Many thanks

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.close('all')

mydateparser2 = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y")
colnames2=['Date','Net sales', 'Cost of sales']
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'account-test.csv', parse_dates = ['Date'] , date_parser = mydateparser2, index_col='Date')
df2= df2.filter(items=colnames2)
df2 = df2.sort_values('Date')

print (df2.info())
print (df2)

fig = plt.figure()

plt.bar(df2.index.values, df2['Net sales'], color='red', label='Net sales'  )
plt.ylim(500000,2800000)
plt.show()
plt.legend(loc=4)
```

Resulting output (to show data types)

```python
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 15 entries, 2005-12-31 to 2019-12-31
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Net sales        15 non-null int64
Cost of sales    15 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 360.0 bytes
None
            Net sales  Cost of sales
Date                                
2005-12-31    1161400         907200
2006-12-31    1193100         928300
2007-12-31    1171100         888100
2008-12-31    1324900        1035700
2009-12-31    1108300         859800
2010-12-31    1173600         891000
2011-12-31    1392400        1050300
2012-12-31    1578200        1171500
2013-12-31    1678200        1224200
2014-12-31    1855500        1346700
2015-12-31    1861200        1328400
2016-12-31    2004300        1439700
2017-12-31    1973300        1421500
2018-12-31    2189100        1608300
2019-12-31    2355700        1715300
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just tried it and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to plot too many bars on a small plot. Try `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6)` to have a bigger plot. You can also pass `width=0.9` to your `bar` command:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
df.plot.bar(y='Net sales', width=0.9, ax=ax)  # modify width to your liking
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. I need to plot the Date on the x-axis and 'Net sales' column on Y in a bar-chart format. Later on, I'm planning on overlaying a line chart on top with Dates against another variable.

Comment: Sorry, it should've been `y='Net sales'` instead of `x='Net sales'`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to add a line graph to this on top on a different y-axis scale how do I do that? I tried using something like the code below but can't pass in ax2 to plot <br/>
ax2 = ax.twinx()  # set up the 2nd axis<br/>
plt.plot(df1.index.values, df1['GBP'], color='red', label='GBP')

Comment: Try `df1.plot(y='GBP', color='red', ax=ax2)`.

Comment: Thank you, this is getting me further. Appreciate your patience. If the X-axis values (also datetime format) on the 2nd dataset df1 is different to the first data set (the 2nd dataset is much bigger but covers the same range as the first), will this work as well?  
  
I'm getting a error copied below which look like maybe due one dataset having different/more x-values that the first?  
  
    **ERROR: KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([ 1.9055,  1.8952, ... ,  1.3079, 1.31215],\n             dtype='float64', length=3798)] are in the [columns]**